# GCC /clang not present on BSD, and unable to install it

Tags: gcc, freebsd, bsd

I have a freebsd 8.4 machine. I want to use to use pyinstaller to create a binary for freebsd. However it looks like pyinstaller does not support freebsd by default so i have to go in the bootloader and create stuff specific to the target system.

This is giving me errors that gcc/cc is not found on the system. Here is the first error message

```
Platform                                 : FreeBSD-64bit detected 
Checking for 'gcc' (C compiler)          : not found 
Checking for 'clang' (C compiler)        : not found
```

So then i try to install gcc via ports. I do this

```
cd /usr/ports/lang/gcc49 
make install
```

It fails :

```
checking whether the C compiler works... no
```

So i checked in the file system and there is no gcc or clang or cc. It only has ccache. Here are the details from /usr/bin

```
CC -> /usr/local/bin/ccache
gcc -> /usr/local/bin/ccache
```

There is nothing in /usr/local/bin (either CC or GCC)

so if i just do gcc at the command line i get this :

```
ccache: FATAL: Could not find compiler "gcc" in PATH
```

how do i fix this. This thing is driving me nuts. pkg install is also not working with error "No repositories found "

Comment: Do you have root? if yes, you can install a binary package of gcc or clang.

Comment: yes i do have root. From where do i get the binary ?

Comment: setenv PACKAGESITE http://ftp-archive.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD-Archive/old-releases/i386/8.4-RELEASE/packages/All

Answer (score 1):

On FreeBSD 8.4 the standard compiler is gcc (4.2), and it's located in /usr/bin. It has to be there.
It seems that ccache installation created some problem removing/overwriting something. ccache package installs compiler links in /usr/local/libexec/ccache, but if you installed it manually I'm not sure what happened.
FreeBSD 8.4 is not maintained anymore and there's no package repository anymore for it.

My suggestion is to update your system to FreeBSD 10.2 and use clang, that's the new standard compiler.